# How to access the form element and the action attribute using JavaScript in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, struts2, struts-1

In Struts 1 you can access the form element and action in JavaScript using following syntax:

```
document.forms.elements
```

and

```
document.form.action
```

In Struts 2 does not exist form classes, and for migration from Struts 1 to Struts 2 I've used `ModelDriven` interface to provide a model object pushed into the `ValueStack` in addition to the action.

How to access the form action attribute in Struts2?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can't access server-side objects either it Struts1 or Struts2. But you can access `<form>` element and its action attribute like this

```
<s:form name="formName" ...

document.forms["formName"].action
```

Comment: Updated to reflect action usage.